# How to access wordpress-docker site on another computer in network

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I created WordPress website and configure it within the Docker. The site displays all it's contains locally correctly. Now I want to access that website from the another machine within same network but it did not display all the contents correctly. it displays only the text. no images and the applied theme is not displays. I think problem is `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306` but how to change that. I access my site locally at `http://localhost:8000/`

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 4443:443
    networks:
      - back
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - back
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
    networks:
      - back
networks:
  back:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Is it possible that your WordPress site needs to have the external URL configured so that the client browser knows the correct URL to ask for these assets?
Have you checked the URL that the missing assets are using in the remote client browser?

Answer (score -2):

From another system in the same network, you can call the WordPress website using the IP of the System where your docker container is running.

For Example, Let say you are running the WordPress Container in System A.
Find the System IP of A It will be like 192.168.0.10

Then from System B Call 192.168.0.10:8000 This will work for you.

Comment: No, it won't, not by default at least. By default docker-wordpress runs on virtual host with hostname `localhost`, and if you visit the IP address, it will promptly redirect you to `http://localhost`, which obviously won't work from another machine.